# Cannot use Youtube Api reference in visual studio 2017 RC

Tags: .net, youtube-api, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I'm using the new Visual Studio 2017 RC to create a Library project (.net Standars 1.3) and i need the Youtube Api.
I added the package via nuget succefully.[image]

But when I want to add the reference in a class VS doesn't see the library

[image]

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to make this work.
By modifing the .csproj file and changing the package NetStandard.Library from version 1.6.1 to 1.6 and pointing the targetFramework to .netstandard1.3